# what does "drinking in some advanced analytics wizardry" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> (If you’re a data junkie and feel like drinking in some advanced analytics wizardry, check out Avinash Kaushik’s bad-ass blog post on cLTV here.)

what does "drinking in some advanced analytics wizardry" mean?

Comment: In addition to what it means, it's a so-called "mixed metaphor". http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mixed+metaphor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **drink something in** is a figure of speech meaning to absorb it deeply, usually taking pleasure in doing so. It's normally used to refer to knowledge, learning, or information in general.

**Analytics** is the science of analysing something - taking it apart and looking closer at it to "see how it works". It can refer to many things, from computer analytics to population analytics.

**Wizardry** is used figuratively to refer to extremely advanced skills or techniques in a particular field - in this case, "analytics wizardry" refers to advanced analytics techniques, I'd imagine. The idea is that the techniques are so novel and effective that to a novice or layperson they might seem almost like magic.

Overall, you could rephrase it as:

> (If you feel like...) absorbing some very interesting analytics ideas...

Comment: RE: "It's normally used to refer to knowledge, learning, or information in general." Perhaps, but it's also used for things involving the senses, like hearing; for example, [_drink in the music](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22drink+in+the+music%22&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&oq=&gs_l=)._